# Scala Generic Trait Factory

Tags: scala, generics, traits

In my project I have many events that are very similar. Here's a shortened example:

```
object Events {
  final case class UpdatedCount(id: Int, prevValue: Double, newValue: Double) 
      extends PropertyEvent[Double]
  final case class UpdatedName(id: Int, prevValue: String, newValue: String) 
      extends PropertyEvent[String]
}
```

The trait looks like this:

```
trait PropertyEvent[A] {
  val id: Int
  val prevValue: A
  val newValue: A
}
```

There is a factory that is used to get the appropriate event at runtime. This gets called by another generic method that uses partial functions to get the `preValue` and `newValue`:

```
object PropertyEventFactory{
  def getEvent[A, B <: PropertyEvent[A]](id: Int, preValue: A, newValue: A, prop: B): PropertyEvent[A]= prop match{
    case UpdatedCount(_,_,_) => UpdatedCount(id, preValue, newValue)
    case UpdatedName(_,_,_) => UpdatedName(id, preValue, newValue)
  }
}
```

IntelliJ's intelliSense complains about the `preValue` and `newValue`, but the compiler is able to figure it out and build successfully.

Here is a basic spec to show how this might get called:

```
"Passing UpdatedCount to the factory" should "result in UpdatedCount" in {
    val a = PropertyEventFactory.getEvent(0, 1d,2d, UpdatedCount(0,0,0))
    assert(a.id == 0)
    assert(a.prevValue == 1)
    assert(a.newValue == 2)
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this by passing `UpdatedCount` as a type instead of an object? Creating a temporary version of `UpdatedCount` just to get the actual `UpdatedCount` Event has code smell to me. I've tried many ways but end up with other issues. Any ideas?

**Edit 1:**
Added the `getEvent` calling function and some additional supporting code to help demonstrate the pattern of use.

Here is the basic entity that is being updated. Forgive the use of vars in the case class as it makes the examples much simpler.

```
final case class BoxContent(id: Int, var name: String, var count: Double, var stringProp2: String, var intProp: Int){}
```

The command used to request an update:

```
object Commands {
  final case class BoxContentUpdateRequest(requestId: Long, entity: BoxContent, fields: Seq[String])
}
```

Here is a persistent actor that receives request to update a `BoxContent` in a `Box`. The method that calls the factory is in here in the `editContentProp` function:

```
class Box extends PersistentActor{

  override def persistenceId: String = "example"

  val contentMap: BoxContentMap = new BoxContentMap()

  val receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case request: BoxContentUpdateRequest =>
      val item = request.entity
      request.fields.foreach{
        case "name" => editContentProp(item.id, item.name, contentMap.getNameProp, contentMap.editNameProp, UpdatedName.apply(0,"",""))
        case "count" => editContentProp(item.id, item.count, contentMap.getCountProp, contentMap.editCountProp, UpdatedCount.apply(0,0,0))
        case "stringProp2" => /*Similar to above*/
        case "intProp" => /*Similar to above*/
        /*Many more similar cases*/
      }
  }

  val receiveRecover: Receive = {case _ => /*reload and persist content info here*/}


  private def editContentProp[A](key: Int, newValue: A, prevGet: Int => A,
                             editFunc: (Int, A) => Unit, propEvent: PropertyEvent[A]) = {
    val prevValue = prevGet(key)
    persist(PropertyEventFactory.getEvent(key, prevValue, newValue, propEvent)) { evt =>
      editFunc(key, newValue)
      context.system.eventStream.publish(evt)
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit2:**
The suggestion made in the comments to expose a factory method for each event and then pass the factory method seems to be best approach.

Here is the modified `Box` class:

```
class Box extends PersistentActor{

  override def persistenceId: String = "example"

  val contentMap: BoxContentMap = new BoxContentMap()

  val receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case request: BoxContentUpdateRequest =>
      val item = request.entity
      request.fields.foreach{
        case "name" => editContentProp(item.id, item.name, contentMap.getNameProp, contentMap.editNameProp, PropertyEventFactory.getNameEvent)
        case "count" => editContentProp(item.id, item.count, contentMap.getCountProp, contentMap.editCountProp, PropertyEventFactory.getCountEvent)
        case "stringProp2" => /*Similar to above*/
        case "intProp" => /*Similar to above*/
        /*Many more similar cases*/
      }
  }

  val receiveRecover: Receive = {case _ => /*reload and persist content info here*/}

  private def editContentProp[A](key: Int, newValue: A, prevGet: Int => A,
                                 editFunc: (Int, A) => Unit, eventFactMethod: (Int, A, A) => PropertyEvent[A]) = {
    val prevValue = prevGet(key)
    persist(eventFactMethod(key, prevValue, newValue)) { evt =>
      editFunc(key, newValue)
      context.system.eventStream.publish(evt)
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the modified `PropertyEventFactory`:

```
object PropertyEventFactory{
  def getCountEvent(id: Int, preValue: Double, newValue: Double): UpdatedCount = UpdatedCount(id, preValue, newValue)
  def getNameEvent(id: Int, preValue: String, newValue: String): UpdatedName = UpdatedName(id, preValue, newValue)
}
```

If one of the commenters who suggested this approach want to propose an answer with this content I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: If you know the event type when you call `getEvent`, why not have a separate factory method for each event and just called the appropriate method?

Comment: `getEvent` gets called by a another generic method, so I doesn't know the event type. It has 2 function arguments (to get the `preValue` and `newValue` values) and a `PropertyEvent[A]` argument that then it passes to `getEvent` when it makes its request.

Comment: I think we need to see the calling function, since that may be where the problem is. But in general you can't use a type parameter to make decisions about how to process data, you need a value for that.

Comment: Why your example compiles, baffles me. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: Responding to first comment: `def getEvent[A, B <: PropertyEvent[A]](id: Int, preValue: A, newValue: A, fact: (Int, A, A) => B): PropertyEvent[A] = fact(id, preValue, newValue)` and than call it using `PropertyEventFactory3.getEvent(0, 1d, 2d, UpdatedCount.apply)`

Comment: @Tim, I added the calling function

Comment: wait, all you're doing is implementing the copy method right? If you have an UpdatedCount(1,2,3) and you want it to return an UpdatedCount(4,5,6) all you have to do is: `val a = UpdatedCount(1,2,3); a.copy(id = 4, prevValue = 5, newValue = 6)` That is all your `getEvent` function is doing. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It seems to me,  that first comment by Tim makes most sense.  Just pass around the factory method.  Companion object of case classes already comes with a predefined factory.  Just use 'CaseClass.apply'

Comment: I proposed an accepted answer in my edit. If anyone who helped would like to officially propose the solution, I'll happily upvote. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, @ygor, I see what you are saying, so I can get rid of the factory object even and just use: `case "name" => editContentProp(item.id, item.name, contentMap.getNameProp, contentMap.editNameProp, UpdatedName.apply)` for example, nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt to summarize an answer.

First of all, there is no such thing as a generic factory for your trait. Your trait `PropertyEvent` only specifies three `vals`, which every subclass of the trait must fulfill **after** creation. Every class, which implements the trait, can have very different constructors and/or factories.

So, you really need to "enumerate" those factories manually somewhere. Your first attempt works, but it really suffers from code smell and frankly, I am very surprised, that it even compiles. Scala compiler must somehow be able to narrow down the generic `A` type to a concrete type, once inside a `match`/`case` of a case class.

If you try something like this:

```
object PropertyEventFactory2 {
  def getEvent[A, B <: PropertyEvent[A]](id: Int, preValue: A, newValue: A, prop: Class[B]): B = prop.getName match {
    case "org.example.UpdatedCount" => UpdatedCount(id, preValue, newValue)
    case "org.example.UpdatedName" => UpdatedName(id, preValue, newValue)
  }
}
```

Than this does not compile. You'd need to cast `preValue` and `newValue` to the appropriate type and this also is a smelly code.

You could create the event before calling `editContentProp`:

```
case "name" => {
    val event = UpdatedName(item.id, contentMap.getNameProp(item.id), item.name)
    editContentProp(item.id, item.name, contentMap.getNameProp, contentMap.editNameProp, event)
}
```

However, all your `case` branches would repeat the same structure, which is a kind of code duplication. You already recognized it, which is good.

So your best choice really is to pass in a factory for every event. And because all your events are case classes, for every case class you receive a factory method for free, generated by Scala compiler. The factory method resides in the companion object of the case class and it is simply called `CaseClass.apply`

This leads to the final form of your `case` branch:

```
case "name" => editContentProp(item.id, item.name, contentMap.getNameProp, contentMap.editNameProp, UpdatedName.apply)
```

which is consumed by parameter:

```
eventFactMethod: (Int, A, A)
```

Comment: Usage of `CaseClass.apply` is highlighted in PlayFramework's forms: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms